# How to get the row numbers of a row title in a pivot table using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pivot table in pandas that looks like this:

[image]

How do I get the row numbers of the Categories in Column A?

Here is how I construct the pivot table:

```
labor_table_rank = pd.pivot_table(labor_data, margins='True', values='Labor Cost', index=['Rank', 'Employee'], columns=['Date'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Comment: that's a very confusing statement, that's not pandas, that's excel. And that's not a pivot table, that's just plain text on a spreadsheet

Comment: show your created pandas table in code

Comment: Next time, instead of "replicating" your pandas data frame with excel, post your `df.head().to_dict()` as _text_ and your expected output. That'll help people answer you!

Comment: ```df[df['A'].notna()]```?

Comment: @Yuca I attached the pandas code I used.  The excel screenshot is what the dataframe looks like when it gets output into excel.

Comment: @AaronRotem Hi, we're not being dificult here but it's really hard to provide quality feedback with what you're currently sharing, please review how to provide a [mcve] in the meantime

Comment: I understand, I am just not sure what else I could provide.  I am looking to get the row number(In the picture 2 and 6) of the items titled 'Category 1' and 'Category 2.'  What other information would I need to provide that would help? @Yuca

Comment: well, you're writing it to excel, so you know what offsets you need. You don't need to interact with excel from within Python, so it is really not clear what you're asking

Comment: Before I export it to excel I want to format it but to do that I need to know the row numbers of the Category items. @Yuca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the following test DataFrame (*labor_data*):

```
         Rank Employee     Date  Labor Cost
0  Category 1    Sub 1  2019-01       200.0
1  Category 1    Sub 1  2019-02        21.0
2  Category 1    Sub 2  2019-01       210.0
3  Category 1    Sub 2  2019-02        11.0
4  Category 1    Sub 3  2019-01       220.0
5  Category 2    Sub 4  2019-01       230.0
6  Category 2    Sub 5  2019-01       240.0
7  Category 2    Sub 6  2019-01       250.0
8  Category 2    Sub 6  2019-02         7.1
```

Pivot table (*labor_table_rank*) generated from the above DataFrame is:

```
Date                 2019-01  2019-02     All
Rank       Employee                          
Category 1 Sub 1       200.0     21.0   221.0
           Sub 2       210.0     11.0   221.0
           Sub 3       220.0      NaN   220.0
Category 2 Sub 4       230.0      NaN   230.0
           Sub 5       240.0      NaN   240.0
           Sub 6       250.0      7.1   257.1
All                   1350.0     39.1  1389.1
```

As *Excel* renders this table slightly different than *Pandas*,
let's start from a correction of your picture:

*Category 1* does not occupy its own row, but it is the value of
the first MultiIndex level in the first row with this rank, in this case row *0* (assuming that the row numbers start from *0*).

The same pertains to row with *Category 2*.

In the above table, rows with non-empty categories (*Rank* column)
are row *0* and *3*.

Note that row *6* has also non-empty *Rank* column, but this is only the
*margin row*, not a Category, hence it should not be included in the row number list. So the proposition by *Juan* expressed in his comment is "too broad".

To get your row number list, proceed as follows:

Generate a "shaddow" DataFrame (*df*) with index reset to consecutive
numbers (starting from *0*), which are also row numbers:

```
df = labor_table_rank.reset_index()
```

The result is:

```
Date        Rank Employee  2019-01  2019-02     All
0     Category 1    Sub 1    200.0     21.0   221.0
1     Category 1    Sub 2    210.0     11.0   221.0
2     Category 1    Sub 3    220.0      NaN   220.0
3     Category 2    Sub 4    230.0      NaN   230.0
4     Category 2    Sub 5    240.0      NaN   240.0
5     Category 2    Sub 6    250.0      7.1   257.1
6            All            1350.0     39.1  1389.1
```

Note that *Data* name in the header row is the name of the **column** index
and has nothing in common with the **row** index just below (it has no name).

Then, to get the row numbers you want, run:

```
df.index[df.Rank.ne(df.Rank.shift()) & df.Rank.ne('All')].to_list()
```

The result is:

```
[0, 3]
```

just as it should be.